# Minecraft Forge 1.8.9 Jar

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

i need the forge 1.8.9 jar for a project as external jar. Anyone knows how to get it? I couldnt find any download, just for 1.7.10.

Greetings

Comment: A request for an off-site resource is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Why don't you simply look at the official forge site? All versions are available there. This takes literally 5 seconds if you google it...

Comment: @QBrute nah u cant find a 1.8.9 jar there. only the installer & src

Comment: @Kjell http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.8.9.html -> click on "Universal" -> Download jar

Comment: @QBrute thats not the one iam looking for. I uploaded the one i have for 1.7.10, take a look at it, you can see the difference. [link](https://www.file-upload.net/download-12585431/Forge.jar.html)

Comment: Why do you need it for 1.8.9? You should be looking for newer ones if you about to start a new project

Comment: https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.8.9.html

Comment: Wait, are you the same guy that asked on the Forge forums? Weren't you told that what you're trying to do is illegal?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not about just universalf forge jar (and you are not!):

The thing you are trying to do is unnecessary and **ILLEGAL**. Please stop. Use minecraft forge or alternative modding methods.